# UAE Phone number regular expression

Tags: regex

I am building a regular expression for UAE numbers. I managed to run few cases but some how its not validating all.

Here is what I came up with.

To Validate numbers starting with: 00971 or +971 below expression works fine.

```
/^((\+971|00971){1}(2|3|4|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56){1}([0-9]{7}))$/
```

e.g. `00971551234567`

Now to validate numbers starting without `00971` or `+971`, I combined below expression with above:

```
/^((050|051|052|055|056){1}([0-9]{7}))$/
```

e.g. `0551234567`

### The Problem

Somehow below expression is not working to validate phone numbers like 041234567

```
/^((02|03|04|06|07|09){1}([0-9]{7}))$/
```

I tried combining all of expression in one expression but it wasn't working, then I realized only above expression wasn't working.

```
         [Country][area][7 digit number]
Pattern: +971 55 1234567
```

Expression should accept numbers like:

- `00971551234567`
- `+971551234567`
- `+97141234567`
- `0551234567`
- `041234567`

How can I make my regex work?

Comment: could you post some examples for strings that would be matched and wouldn't

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: Your "problem" expression works on the example phone number.

Comment: what is the length or are [Country] and [area] optional in the expression?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: i am using this expression in Javascript. The mentioned expression doesn't work.

Comment: @Dalorzo Yes, Country and area can be optional. Please check valid expressions mentioned above.

Comment: did you want to allow the last 7 digits only?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?:\+971|00971|0)?(?:50|51|52|55|56|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uX8nW2/1)

```
> /^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?:2|3|4|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7}$/.test("041234567")
true
> /^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?:2|3|4|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7}$/.test("00971551234567")
true
> /^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?:2|3|4|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7}$/.test("009715512345671")
false
```

---

```
> "041234567".match(/^(?:\+971|00971|0)?(?:50|51|52|55|56|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$/m); 
[ '041234567',
  index: 0,
  input: '041234567' ]
```

Comment: even my expression works on regex101.com. Having said that, even your regex is validating all patterns except 041234567 in Javascript.
value.match(/^(?:\+971|00971|0)?(?:50|51|52|55|56|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$/) is returning false.

Comment: you missed my point. The regular expression that i mentioned in my question also works on regex101.com. Check my previous comment :-/

Comment: /^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?:2|3|4|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7}$/.test("041234567") is returning false in my case. the rest are returning true. 
(/^(?:\+971|00971|0)?(?:50|51|52|55|56|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$/).test(value) in jquery validator is returning false.

Comment: OMG, it's returning true for me. Please check the number of digits you entered.

Comment: I will mark your answer accepted

Comment: 0588149014 valid mobile number but does not come in it
^(?:\+971|00971|0)?(?:50|51|52|55|56|57|58|59|2|3|4|6|7|9)\d{7}$

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the UAE number format, but from your examples I came up with the following:

```
^(?:\+971|0(0971)?)(?:[234679]|5[01256])[0-9]{7}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eC2cU2/1)

Comment: Looks like I'm late... but my regex makes the country or `0` prefix mandatory so I'll keep this answer for now

Comment: Use this instead, to prevent the use of backtracking and shorten it a bit: `^(?:\+971|0(0971)?)(?:[234679]|5[01256])\d{7}$`

Comment: @Unihedron Indeed, that's better... I'm guilty of copy/pasting the OP's regex without thinking too much. But I'd still use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` in case someone tries to use this regex in something else than JS.